# List not showing in custom added module

Tags: php, vtiger

I added a custom module in vtigercrm 5.4 using vtlib/moduledir/5.4 by copying this folder.

Everything works fine except one thing, I added hard coded data in database (I create table for my custom module and link this to vtiger_field, vtiger_blocks, vtiger_crmentity, etc...), but this data is not showing when I open my module. I changed table name and columns name in module.php, but everything fails. Can anyone tell me how I show my data in to this list.

[image]

got something. I add get_related_list function in vtiger_relatedlists table. and create this function in module.php. and in function I add this code:

---

```
global $adb; 
$header = array("RabateName");
$data = "SELECT  RabateName FROM vtiger_OrganisationRabate where vtiger_OrganisationRabate.OrganisationRabate_id = ?";
$result = $adb->pquery($data,array(495));
$accountname = array(array());
while($resultrow = $adb->fetchByAssoc($result)) 
{
    $accountname[]=$resultrow;
}
$return_value = array('header'=>$header,'entries'=>$accountname);
return $return_value;
```

but again fails,still not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding module hard coded in database details. you are missing some of thew table.
So my suggestion is to add module by using script.

Here is the script.

```
<?php 

// Turn on debugging level
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');

$module = new Vtiger_Module();
$module->name = 'Store';
$module->save();

$module->initTables();
$module->initWebservice();

$menu = Vtiger_Menu::getInstance('Support');
$menu->addModule($module);

$block1 = new Vtiger_Block();
$block1->label = 'Organization Information';
$module->addBlock($block1); //to create a new block

$field0 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field0->name = 'organization_name';
$field0->label = 'Organization Name';
$field0->table = $module->basetable; 
$field0->column = 'organization_name';
$field0->columntype = 'VARCHAR(100)';
$field0->uitype = 2;
$field0->typeofdata = 'V~M';
$module->setEntityIdentifier($field0); //to insert values in entity folder
$block1->addField($field0); //to add field in block


$field1 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field1->name = 'store_id_auto';
$field1->label = 'Store ID';
$field1->table = $module->basetable; 
$field1->column = 'store_id_auto';
$field1->columntype = 'VARCHAR(100)';
$field1->uitype = 4;
$field1->typeofdata = 'V~O';
$block1->addField($field1);

//Do not change any value for filed2.
$field2 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field2->name = 'assigned_user_id';
$field2->label = 'Assigned To';
$field2->table = 'vtiger_crmentity'; 
$field2->column = 'smownerid';
$field2->columntype = 'int(19)';
$field2->uitype = 53;
$field2->typeofdata = 'V~M';
$block1->addField($field2);

$filter1 = new Vtiger_Filter();
$filter1->name = 'All';
$filter1->isdefault = true;
$module->addFilter($filter1);

// Add fields to the filter created
$filter1->addField($field0, 1);
$filter1->addField($field1, 2);
$filter1->addField($field2, 3);


/** Set sharing access of this module */
$module->setDefaultSharing('Private'); 
/** Enable and Disable available tools */
$module->enableTools(Array('Import', 'Export'));
$module->disableTools('Merge');

 ?>
```

First create a module folder in modules and copy files from vtlib/ModuleDir/5.4.0 file to the folder created in modules/newmodule

Change name of ModuleFile.js, ModuleFile.php, ModuleFileAjax.php with your module name(with no space).

Keep in mind, During changing name of ModuleFileAjax.php just Replace ModuleFile  with name of Module.

Go to modulename.php to change the class name, $table_name (6values change), $table_index (4values change).

Table index is nothing but the moduleid(ex. taskid) which is auto generated after modulecreated.

Comment: i know this, but i dont know how to run this script.

Comment: Create one file and named it with anything. Suppose it is create.php. Now place the code in this file which i have given. Now put the file in your project folder where your index file placed. now in browser enter your projectname and then this file name(create.php) and press enter. Thats it.

For Example
    projectname.com/create.php

Comment: i did that,but nothing happens. but found a solution of this problem. this problem is solved by change this line '$rowdata = $this->change_key_case($result->FetchRow());' to ' $rowdata = $result->FetchRow();' in PearDatabase.php (/include/database/PeardataBase.php). i don't know why this thing is happening. but this solves my problem. anyway thanks for the help. i learn something from you.